# hyperledger composer: Calling a REST API (GET) from Transaction Processor Functions

Tags: hyperledger-composer

Would like to make a GET call out of a transaction processor functions.
Found docu how to make a post call here: https://hyperledger.github.io/composer/integrating/call-out.html, but nothing about making a GET call.
Any idea appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, there isn't any way at present to do a GET. As the link you provide suggests the POST is an experimental feature and we would welcome feedback suggestions so raising a git issue at https://github.com/hyperledger/composer would be good way to provide feedback, suggestions and use cases/